# Mandrill SMTP with Swiftmail in Laravel - works local, breaks on hosting

Tags: laravel, smtp, swiftmailer, mandrill

When users are registered Laravel fires of a welcome email using Swiftmail configured to use SMTP with Mandrill. With the existing config, this works perfectly on my local installation.

When moving to the production server (Unmanaged, CentOS with WHM/Cpanel), the first HELO fails, giving this error:

```
Swift_TransportException in AuthHandler.php line 181:

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "info@mydomain.com" using 2 possible 
authenticators

in AuthHandler.php line 181
at Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler->afterEhlo(object(Swift_SmtpTransport)) in 
EsmtpTransport.php line 307
```

All other questions I can find with this error are about Gmail needing to have it's authentication weakened to allow the connection. This is directly with Mandrill so such things can't be the issue.

I've already checked the correct port (578) is open - nmap says it is.

That the credentials in `mail.php` are valid - API key is correct, so is user information.

And that the server can access the remote server - I can telnet smtp.mandrillapp.com without issue.

I'm running out of things to test for to fix.

Any suggestions welcome, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that your configuration is the same locally as it is in production?

Comment: @James - I'm sure. My local was cloned from the production server initially and I've made no alterations to the config that I haven't then reversed. Even just checked side by side, unless there's config anywhere besides `env` and `mail.php`?